# Use if to judge why the result of two identical parameters is 'False'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, helper

This is my code. I can't get the data I want.I found that although my 'address' and the 'address' obtained from the data look the same, they are not equal

```
        import requests
        import json

        address = '0xF5565F298D47C95DE222d0e242A69D2711fE3E89'


        url = f'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address={address}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10000&sort=asc'
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36',
        }

        rsp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        result = json.loads(rsp.text)

        result = result['result']

        gas_list = []
        val_list = []

        for item in result:
            if 'from' in item:
                index = result.index(item)

                if result[index]['from'] == address:

                    wei = 10 ** 18
                    gasPrice = result[index]['gasPrice']
                    gasUsed = result[index]['gasUsed']
                    value = result[index]['value']

                    gas = gasPrice * gasUsed / wei
                    v = value / wei

                    gas_list.append(gas)
                    val_list.append(v)


        total_gas = sum(gasl) 
        total_val = sum(val)

        print(total_gas)
        print(total_val)
```

I guess it may be the problem of id(), but I don't know how to solve it. I've been wondering for a long time. I'm a novice in Python. Please help me

```
        if result[index]['from'] == address:
```

Comment: Have you tried printing/logging `result[index]['from']` (or stepping through in a debugger) to find out what the actual type and value is? That'd be the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Your address has uppercase letters while the returned `from` addresses have lowercase  letters, therefore the strings don't match.

Try testing them with

```
result[index]['from'].upper() == address
```

or switching yours to be lowercase.

I found this out by visiting the URL you gave and having a look at what was returned. A useful technique for services like this that provide JSON responses, as it's all plain text and readable in a browser.

Comment: wow! I didn't notice the problem with the letters. It's working. Thank you